Spring Cloud Gateway with OIDC/Oauth2 refresh tokens and max-reuse=0
I'm trying to configure an Api Gateway using Spring Cloud Gateway and the authorization code flow.
The authorization server is configured to allow refresh-tokens for renewal of access-tokens, but we are not allowed to handle reuse of a refresh-token. As soon as a new access-token is created, a new refresh-token is attached and the previous refresh-token is revoked.
This works fine as long as our web client sends requests in a moderate pace, but I think we have run into a race condition when it is time for renewal of the current access-token:
If two or more requestes are issued from the browser at the same time, request 1 will trigger a refresh against the authorization server. Before request 1 completes, request 2 hits the gateway and will also trigger a refresh-operation.
The first request to the auth-server will complete normally, but the second will fail since the refresh token is revoked.
Are there any configuration that could handle this setup?
A possible solution would perhaps be to create a session-based lock for refresh-requests, but this seems like a non-trivial alternative?

Maybe you could have a look into the conditions under which the authorization server revokes preceding refresh token? If you could configure the authorization server to not revoke the former refresh token, or better to revoke it with a slight delay, then your problem would be gone.

Unfortunately we aren't allowed to modify the configuration of the authorization server, and disabling the reuse of refresh tokens is a hard requirement from the security department.
Otherwise it would have been an easier way forward!

Maybe is it possible to evaluate if there is a new authorized client in session when a refresh token request fails and return this new authorized client instead of propagating an error?
Something a bit like that:
static class FairPlayerTokenOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider implements OAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider {
    private RefreshTokenOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider delegate = new RefreshTokenOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider();
    private final OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepo;

    public FairPlayerTokenOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider(OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepo) {
        this.authorizedClientRepo = authorizedClientRepo;
    }

    @Override
    public OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorize(OAuth2AuthorizationContext context) {
        try {
            return delegate.authorize(context);
        } catch (ClientAuthorizationException e) {
            final Optional<OAuth2AuthorizedClient> reEvaluatedAuthorizedClient = getRequest()
                .flatMap(
                    req -> Optional
                        .ofNullable(
                            authorizedClientRepo.loadAuthorizedClient(context.getClientRegistration().getRegistrationId(), context.getPrincipal(), req)));
            // Maybe, this is just enough
            // if(reEvaluatedAuthorizedClient.isPresent() && ! Objects.equals(reEvaluatedAuthorizedClient.get(), context.getAuthorizedClient())) {
            //     return reEvaluatedAuthorizedClient.get();
            // }
            final var isAccessTokenExpiring = reEvaluatedAuthorizedClient
                .map(OAuth2AuthorizedClient::getAccessToken)
                .map(OAuth2AccessToken::getExpiresAt)
                .map(Instant.now().plusMillis(60000)::isAfter)
                .orElse(true);
            if (isAccessTokenExpiring) {
                throw e;
            }
            return reEvaluatedAuthorizedClient.get();
        }
    }

    static Optional<HttpServletRequest> getRequest() {
        RequestAttributes requestAttributes = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
        if (requestAttributes instanceof ServletRequestAttributes attr) {
            return Optional.ofNullable(attr.getRequest());
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}

As the OAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder accepts any kind of provider, you could try to use the above with OAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder().provider(...) (instead of OAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder().refreshToken())
If you prefer a "lock" mechanism, you could acquire it before calling the delegate and release it after it responds. Be careful to keep this lock state in session.

Thanks for your suggestion, this could be a good starting point.
By the time the second request fails, the first one would probably have completed and be stored in the authorizedClientRepo.
I'll try to verify this during the coming days.

If you set a lock in session with the 1st request and release it only after you updated the authorized client in the repo, others can wait until the lock is released and return the new authorized client from the repo.
